# How to get all the weight updates from Word2Vec

Tags: tensorflow, gensim, word2vec

I am not only interested in the final W0 and W1 (also, to some known as W and W'), but all the variations of these two matrices during the learning.

For now, I am using the gensim implementation, but compared to sklearn, gensim's API is not very well organized in my mind. Hence, I am open to moving to tf if need be, given that getting access to these values would be possible/easier.

I know I can hack the main code; my question is whether there already is a function/variable for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no specific API for seeing individual training example updates, or interim weights mid-training.

But as you've intuited, instead of calling `train()` once, letting it run all epochs and all learning-rate-updates (as is recommended), you could call it one epoch at a time, providing it the right incremental `start_alpha` and `end_alpha` yourself each call, and between the calls look at the word-vectors (aka "projection weights") and hidden-to-output weights (`syn1neg` for default negative-sampling, or `syn1` for hierarchical-softmax).

If you needed more fine-grained reporting, you'd need to modify the source code to add the extra logging/callouts/etc you need.

Comment: Thanks gojomo. I wonder if you could help me understand the difference between syn0 and its variations (under model.wv) and the syn1 family better since the API doesn't do a good job in my mind. In addition, one problem I have is that I am more interested in weight updates for each pair of words (of the skip-gram model), as they are fed into the network. In other words, I want to know how each step of gradient descent affects weight matrices. Using .train(), all I can do is feed in my sentences and the sg pairs will be detected within, hence no access

Comment: `syn0` is the legacy name for the "projection weights" matrix, essentially the word-vectors themselves. (Each row is a projection from a one-hot word-encoding, to a word's dense embedding, the word-vector.) `syn1neg`/`syn1` are the internal NN weights from the 'hidden layer' activations to the final output-node activations. As mentioned above, to report individual updates, you'd have to get deep into the (optimized cython source code) loops used during training. Essentially, if you need to do that, the best (and only) reference is the source code itself.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your feedback.